# How to pass Selected text as parameter in Grails

Tags: grails

Here is my GSP code where I get values from DB

```
<g:select name="questinset" from="${set}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"/>
```

I want to pass selected item text to controller where I get values

```
def questionSet=params.questinset //It shows only value like 1,2,3,4,5
```

I want to get selected text.

Comment: You only post the value of an option in a select, not the text associated with that option.  So you will need to look up the `id`s you're being passed, and get their names

Comment: unless you dont actually care about id in which case your optionKey='name' and optionValue='name. If you need to get actual object then is as Tim states above.'